# Apache mod-rewrite variables

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Apache Mod-Rewrite, I have a problem not a error as such but the following makes both $1 and $2 equal to $1 i.e 'survey'

```
RewriteRule ^((survey|quiz|form|widget))/create$ items/create/?type=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^((survey|quiz|form|widget))/([0-9]+)/edit$ items/edit/?type=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^((survey|quiz|form|widget))/([0-9]+)/delete$ items/delete/?type=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^((survey|quiz|form|widget))/([0-9]+)/results$ items/results/?type=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^((survey|quiz|form|widget))/([0-9]+)/reliability$ items/reliability/?type=$1&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^((survey|quiz|form|widget))/([0-9]+)/publish$ items/publish/?type=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

So it is like

```
/widget/45657/publish
```

will go to

```
/items/publish/?type=widget&id=widget
```

Instead of

```
/items/publish/?type=widget&id=45657
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why two parenthesis? This explain your problem.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(survey|quiz|form|widget)/create$ items/create/?type=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(survey|quiz|form|widget)/([0-9]+)/edit$ items/edit/?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(survey|quiz|form|widget)/([0-9]+)/delete$ items/delete/?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(survey|quiz|form|widget)/([0-9]+)/results$ items/results/?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(survey|quiz|form|widget)/([0-9]+)/reliability$ items/reliability/?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(survey|quiz|form|widget)/([0-9]+)/publish$ items/publish/?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

By the way you could optimize your rules with something close to:

```
RewriteRule ^(survey|quiz|form|widget)/create$ items/create/?type=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(survey|quiz|form|widget)/([0-9]+)/(edit|delete|results|reliability|publish)$ items/$3/?type=$1&id=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Ain't that shorter? `;)`

Comment: Many thanks, I did in fact realize this after that because I was using 2 brackets that it created $1 and $2 the same and then $3 was in fact the id.